# Hiding a div while hovering over another?

Tags: html, css

In the code below I tried to hide the second `div` named `hide_div` by hovering over 'show_div', but the code did'nt work, this supposed to be a very simple code, but why is it not working??!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Trying to hide a div</title>

    <style type="text/css">
     .show_div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color:red;
      display: block;
     }
     .hide_div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: orange;
      margin-top: 50px;
      display: block;
     }
     .show_div:hover.hide_div{
      display:none;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="show_div">
    </div>

    <div class="hide_div">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/t5mB3/2/)

Comment: Please show your sample.

Comment: it does not work because hide_div is not a child of show_div

Comment: Try putting the code in a fiddle always

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like this:

```
.show_div:hover + .hide_div {
display:none;
```

Please note that this will work only if the `.hide_div` is direct sibling of the `.show_div`.
If, for some reason, you have to put an element between them, use this instead:

```
.show_div:hover ~ .hide_div {
display:none;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RY58/)

Comment: Yes" .show_div:hover + .hide_div {
display:none;" Does work fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this CSS:

```
.show_div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color:red;
        display: block;
        }
        .hide_div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: block;
        }
        .show_div:hover + div{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: !important make the css invalid in w3c validator;

Answer (score 0):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/rc4X6/

```
.show_div:hover + .hide_div 
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".show_div").hover(function() {
      $(".hide_div ").hide();   
    });

});
```

use it inside script tag

Comment: add jquery file in your project

Comment: He asked for a CSS solution. Moreover, please detail your answer by explaining code and, maybe, add links to corresponding documentation pages.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Trying to hide a div</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .show_div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:red;
    display: block;
    }
    .hide_div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: block;
    }

    </style>
    <script>
    function z()
    {
        document.getElementById("hid").style.display="none";

    }
    function zz()
    {
        document.getElementById("hid").style.display="";

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="show_div"  onmouseover="z()" onmouseout="zz()">
    </div>

    <div class="hide_div" id="hid">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```